# SAP Adobe form Text field alignment issue

Tags: adobe, abap

I am displaying the long text of order in the text field of adobe forms. I maintained the long text for order as below:

> `Test first line.`
>
> `Test second Line.`
>
> `Test paragraph: SAP has added several new built-in functions for searching, comparing, and processing character strings.  A few of these functions already existed before release WAS702, like for example, CHARLEN( ) or STRLEN( ).SAP software users, developers, consultants, mentors and students use the SAP Community Network to get help, share ideas, learn, innovate and connect with others.`

While Displaying this form, the paragraph which are having huge lines is not align properly. Please find the below attachment.

[image]

I want those highlighted lines to be aligned with previous lines.I tried to align that long text field from AdobeLifeCycle Designer but didn't work.
Can you please suggest the possible solutions that I can try.

Answer (score 0):

I have some solutions that may help you.

1st solution: I don't know exactly where you tried to set this, but it should be here. In Adobe Designer, you can right-click on the text box to open Paragraph Settings. (Need to set the Field Format to Plain Text Only in Object palette)

[image: Open Paragraph]

Here, the "First" setting is probably set to a different value, so that the first lines start further in.

[image: Paragraph settings]

2nd solution: If you've tried this, the question is how the form gets the text value. If a variable is bound, this should be fine, but if the read is done in the form's Context menu from a text module or include-text, you need to pay attention to which formatting the form uses.

[image: Object settings]

You can find this in the settings of the text field object called "Field Format". "Plain Text Only" will only use the text content and will format the text according to Adobe Form. In this case, this is the correct answer.
But if you want to keep the text element format and edit it, go for "Rich text".

3rd solution: However, there may be another error, which I only had once, but then I ran into a similar problem. I copied the text from a file and the text kept its formatting and I could not change it. I solved this by taking a completely new text field and typing the text in myself. The formatting worked fine on that one.

In such cases, basic questions may arise: is the form active, have you transported it, are you using the right version?

I hope I was able to help with some of the solutions.

Comment: Hi,

I tried these solution but not able to handle that alignment. I am reading the text via read-text fm and binding that data to that field format field.
Is there any other way I can try ?

Comment: Perhaps you could try reading the text in the Context menu and not via the READ TEXT function module. You might try creating a text module (/SMARTFORMS, if available) and linking it in the same way. You can also set text options in it and bind it as "Rich text".

Comment: Hi, Sorry I didn't understand  your solution.vI am working on adobe forms and bindings the fields of odata to text field. the properties I maintained for text field are:
1Allow Multiple Lines 2. Limit length to visible area. 3. Allow page breaks within 
content also filed format is rich text.
apart form that I have set the alignment of paragraph as Right justify 
,but not able to achieve the result

Comment: Did you try "Plain Text Only" and set the "First" option to None in the Paragraph settings, as I wrote in solution 1?